# Why is DirectX 12 Ultimate Disabled on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, directx

Why would DirectX 12 Ultimate be Disabled on Windows 11?

What specifically is Windows 11 looking for?

This is a laptop.  The CPU has integrated Intel UHD Graphics - Intel Iris Xe 11th Gen.  DxDiag is showing that DirectX 12 is Disabled in Windows 11.

[image]

Comment: “What specifically is Windows 11 looking for?” - Hardware that supports the required feature level. Care to provide more specifics by editing your question?

Comment: This is a laptop.  The CPU has integrated Intel UHD graphics.  DxDiag is showing that DirectX 12 is Disabled in Windows 11.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is actually a good question.  Don't people on here know anything?

Comment: @John - “Can you uninstall Direct X Ultimate?” - Direct X 12 **cannot** be uninstalled.

Comment: @John - They are the same thing, Ultimate, is feature level 12_2 which is the current feature level.

Comment: I know a great deal. I know 12_2 (DirectX 12 Ultimate) requires hardware support. As for the downvote you haven’t provided any information about your hardware

Comment: Intel Iris Xe 11th Gen

Comment: What do you mean by "hardware support"?

Comment: Certain feature levels (12_2) requires silicone (I.e hardware) to support, drivers only allow software to use that hardware, the supported DX feature levels of your GPU are documented on Intels website. Your iGPU supports feature level 12_1 and is incapable of supporting 12_2 per the documentation [here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196656/intel-core-i511300h-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz-with-ipu.html). I took a guess at your processor since you failed to provide it

Comment: I am in the process of writing a more detailed and comprehensive answer but I need to see a screenshot of the DXDiag that indicates DX12 is disabled.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Intel UHD does not support DX12. It's only supported by recent Nvidia cards and a few high-end AMD cards. DX12 is relatively new (about 1 year old) so it's very reasonable that most graphics adapters don't support it yet. It will probably take a while but eventually I guess most cards and eventually integrated graphics will also support it, just like it took a while but eventually happened with DX11.

I am not sure though which (if any) graphics cards / integrated graphics adapters could get support via driver update. There is a possibility that DX12 will never be supported on your device.

Comment: “I am not sure though which (if any) graphics cards / integrated graphics adapters could get support via driver update.” DirectX requires hardware support, hardware only supports up to a specific hardware feature level, a driver cannot change the underlying hardware. Feature level 12_2 was released in 2020

Comment: The hardware is the Intel Iris Xe 11th Gen.  What "hardware" or "hardware features" are you referring to?  Do you have any specifics?

Comment: Apparently one (GPU) can more or less claim "Direct3D 12 support" even if it merely supports its lowest feature level (which is 11_0). I have no idea what's the requirement for DirectX 12 to shown as enabled in dxdiag though.

Comment: In order for software to utilize 12_2 (DX12 feature level) the actual silicon must exist to support it.

Comment: @TomYan - It just support at least 12_0. The story behind 11_0 and 12_0 is documented.

Comment: Ah, it seems that there's only a "DirectX 12 Ultimate Enabled" flag, and DirectX 12 **Ultimate** is apparently a synonym to feature level 12_2.

Comment: @TomYan - Yes; apparently; I don’t have a 12_2 card so I cannot confirm if that’s what otherwise would be shown.

Comment: @Ramhound many source I can see here set the bottom line of "Direct3D 12 support" (NOT Ultimate) to feature level 11_0. (Like they'd mark GCN 1 and Haswell iGPU as that.) I have no idea if Microsoft has a "rolling" approach on that though (like they redefine it from time to time).

Comment: @TomYan - I sort of mentioned that. 11_0 and 12_0 differ only in some very specific ways. Regardless, in this case, only 12_1 is supported.

Answer (score 3):

> Why would DirectX 12 Ultimate be Disabled on Windows 11?

Your iGPU must support DirectX feature level 12_2 (also known as DirectX 12 Ultimate). Your specific iGPU only supports feature level 12_1. So while it’s a DirectX 12 capable GPU it doesn’t support the most recently added features.

Source: [DirectX Feature Levels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct3D#Feature_levels)

> DxDiag is showing that DirectX 12 is Disabled in Windows 11.

No; What’s actually shown as being disabled is feature level 12_2 or DirectX 12 Ultimate. Your provided screenshot indicates your hardware supports 12_1. The features added to DirectX by 12_2 requires hardware (silicon) to support it.

Ultimately, while it requires drivers from (Intel, Nvidia, and AMD) to utilize DX12 within software, it’s impossible to add 12_2 (or later) through software alone. The same is true for Vulkan support which also requires silicon to support it.